# How to insert or update based on some condition?

Tags: mysql, insert-update

Can someone please help me with this! I have 2 tables:

1.Existing pricing table with custom date-dependent pricing windows:

```
  id | prod id |   start    |    stop    |   price  
-----+---------+------------+------------+-----------
   1 |   65210 | 2012-01-01 | 2013-01-01 |  5.00     
   2 |   54841 | 2012-02-05 | 2013-03-01 | 15.00     
   3 |   51518 | 2012-01-01 | 2013-01-01 |  5.00     
   4 |    8402 | 2012-01-01 | 2017-01-01 |  5.00     
   5 |    1520 | 2012-01-01 | 2050-01-01 | 12.00     
   6 |     959 | 2013-10-01 | 2018-01-01 |  5.00
```

2."New" pricing data table (used to update table above by each unique `prod id`):

```
 prod id |   start    |    stop    |   price   
  -------+------------+------------+-----------
   65210 | 2013-01-01 | 2025-01-01 |  5.00     
   54841 | 2013-02-05 | 2017-03-01 | 15.00     
     959 | 2013-01-01 | 2017-01-01 |  5.00
```

What's the best way to update the `stop` date in the table 1 with the `stop` date in table 2 assuming it's still "in window"?  If the existing `stop` date is before the "new" `start` date, a new pricing record will be created with the new `start` and `stop` dates.

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to stack overflow.  please show what you have attempted so far, and what is not working.  otherwise your question may be closed because this is not a 'do it for me' site.

Comment: Also, it helps to include the SQL platform you are using.   I am guessing it is mySQL, but you should include the platform as a tag

Comment: And consider providing a sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 0):

*...To update the `stop` date in the table 1 with the `stop` date in table 2 assuming it's still "in window"...*

```sql
UPDATE price p JOIN new_price n
    ON p.prod_id = n.prod_id
   AND n.start BETWEEN p.start AND p.stop
   SET p.stop = n.stop
```

To insert a new record *"...if the existing `stop` date is before the new `start` date..."*

```sql
INSERT INTO price (`prod_id`, `start`, `stop`, `price`)
SELECT n.prod_id, n.start, n.stop, n.price
  FROM new_price n JOIN price p
    ON n.prod_id = p.prod_id
   AND n.start > p.stop
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf8c4/1)** demo